# How can I print all variable of function in lldb trace?

Tags: python, macos, lldb, macos-catalina

I tried at this way:

```
           destination = thread.GetFrameAtIndex(0).GetSymbol().GetName()
            
            # registers = thread.GetFrameAtIndex(0).GetRegisters()
            for x,i in enumerate(thread.GetFrameAtIndex(0).get_arguments()):
                log("arg: {0}: sum: {1} val: {2}".format(x,
                                                         i.GetSummary(),
                                                         i.GetValue()))
                                                                 

            for x, i in enumerate(thread.GetFrameAtIndex(0).GetRegisters()):
                log("reg: {0}: sum: {1} val: {2} desc: ".format(
                    x,
                    i.GetSummary(),
                    i.GetValue(),
                    i.GetObjectDescription()))
```

The idea is to get all the types, value and content of pointer (when lldb can resolve them)
so for example for char *, string, NSString etc. I except that GetSummary() / GetObjectDescription() will be able to resolve them to the actual string.

The problem is when I try to trace `thread.GetFrameAtIndex(0).get_arguments()` always return empty list and the output of  `thread.GetFrameAtIndex(0).GetRegisters()` looks like this:

```
reg: 0: sum: None val: None desc: 
reg: 1: sum: None val: None desc: 
reg: 2: sum: None val: None desc:
```

What I do rung?

My purpose is to add this to call tracer I built in lldb, so in every function the tracer will try to do best efforts to resolve function argument values and in exit it will do best efforts to resolve function return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call GetRegisters, what you get back is an array of the register groups, GPR, Floating Point and whatever else your machine might have.  The register groups don't have values or summaries - though the do have names.  So for instance on intel, I get (in the script interpreter):

```
>>> for reg_group in lldb.frame.GetRegisters():
...     print(reg_group.GetName())
... 
General Purpose Registers
Floating Point Registers
Exception State Registers
```

So you need one more iteration, or if you just want the GPR's they are always first, so:

```
>>> for reg in lldb.frame.GetRegisters()[0]:
...     print(reg)
... 
(unsigned long) rax = 0x0000000100003f50
(unsigned long) rbx = 0x0000000000000000
(unsigned long) rcx = 0x00007ffeefbff768
```

Comment: Thanks, What about the get_arguments()? why is that always empty?

Comment: Are you in a frame with debug info?  Arguments mean arguments from debug info.  It will be empty in any frames w/o debug info.

Comment: No I looking for automatic way to print during the tracing the function argument and the function return values, How can I do that? (just using po or p didn't do the trick, I need something that when lldb know the signature of the function he will automatically extract from the registers  the argument and logs them

Comment: Without knowing the signature of a function you can't know where its arguments are.  They could be in the GPR's, the FPR's or on the stack.  If lldb has debug information for the function, get_arguments will print them.  If you stop in a function, and then use SBThread.StepOut, when it stops SBThread.GetStopReturnValue will give you the return value from that function.  But if the function doesn't have debug info, then lldb again has no way to know what this might be.